# How to apply gravity when an object fall?

Tags: java, gravity, bounce

I have an object(which is a ball) having its position at the top of the screen that fall directly whenever I start running the program. The problem is that the ball fall to its constant speed, I want it to fall accelerating with gravity effects and when it reach the ground, I want it to bounce a few more times before it stop moving. Could someone help me about this?

Here's what I've tried:

```
public class Balls
{
private double x;
private double y;
private double speed;
private double mass;
private final double gravity = -9.8;
private final double width = 100;
private double height = 100;
private final Board board;
private boolean isFalling = false;
private double distance_y;
private double distance_x = 0;

public Balls(double x, double y, double speed, double mass, Board board)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.board = board;
    this.speed = convertToMeterSpeed(speed);
    this.mass = mass;

}

private double convertToMeterSpeed(double speed)
{
    return speed / 3.6;
}

public void moveBall(long dt)
{

    double time = dt / 1e9; // seconds
    double diameter_y = height / 2.0;
    double radius = (diameter_y / 2.0);
    double velocity_y = speed * dt / 1e9;
    distance_y = board.getHeight() - y;

    if (distance_y - radius > 0)
    {
        isFalling = true;
    }

    if (isFalling)
    {
        if (distance_y >= height)
        {
            distance_y = distance_y + (0.5 * gravity * (time * time));  // represents the 1/2,
            distance_y = board.getHeight() - height;
            y += velocity_y;
        }

        else
        {
            isFalling = false;
        }

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {

        }
    }
}


public void render(Graphics2D g2d)
{
         g2d.fillOval((int) x, (int) y, (int) width, (int) height);

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

speed = v0 + gt^2/2,

where

v0 - initial speed

g = 9.81 on Earth.

t - time

Now you can calculate the speed at any time.

Comment: Is this right? Is not the formula `v = u + (a * t)`

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to define a maximum speed (terminal velocity) so your ball doesn't accelerate to an enormous speed. Gravity accelerates at 9.8m/s/s. Once the ball hits the "ground" you just reverse the speed and update the current position to make it bounce, then on your next iteration gravity will be applied again so it will go back down. Eventually, the speed will get to 0 as the ball doesnt bounce so much, and will stop.

Here's an (untested) example:

```
private static final double GRAVITY = 9.8;
private static final double TERMINAL_VELOCITY = 100;
private double speed;
private int current_y;

public void fallAndBounce() {
    speed = speed + GRAVITY;

    if (speed > TERMINAL_VELOCITY) { speed = TERMINAL_VELOCITY; }

    if (current_y >= bottomOfScreen)
    {
        //We have hit the "ground", so bounce back up. Reverse
        //the speed and divide by 4 to make it slower on bouncing.
        //Just change 4 to 2 or something to make it faster.
        speed = -speed/4; 
    } 
    current_y += speed; 
}
```

Comment: you mean I have to make an iteration?

Comment: Your ball will most likely currently be animating during a loop of some kind, so you'll need to add your acceleration and bounce there.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to animate a ball falling, but you are instead writing an algorithm for solving its position given a certain time.

This means you should take your time variable `dt` **completely** out of the equation, and just move your ball with each iteration of a loop **like this:**

```
while (true)
{
    moveBall();
    render();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10)
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

**Also, change your variables slightly:**

```
// Add this to your variables
private final double GRAVITY = -9.8;    // Final variables should be capitalized
private final double TERMINAL_VELOCITY = -30; // Whatever you want it to be
```

**Here is the main change:**

```
public void moveBall()
{
    double diameter_y = height / 2.0;
    double radius = (diameter_y / 2.0);
    double velocity_y = speed * dt / 1e9;
    distance_y = board.getHeight() - y;

    if (distance_y - radius > 0)
    {
        isFalling = true;
    }

    if (isFalling)
    {
        if (height < distance_y)
        {
            if (velocity_y <= TERMINAL_VELOCITY)
                velocity_y += GRAVITY;  // implementing acceleration (gravity)
                                        // just means adding it to velocity.
            y += velocity_y;
        }
```

Really, I don't know how this was possibly working before.